# I have a CircularProgressIndicator in my TextFormField's suffix icon. How to make it smaller?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `CircularProgressIndicator` in my `TextFormField`'s suffix icon. I want to make it smaller.

My code:

```
TextFormField(
  …
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    …
    suffixIcon: const SizedBox(
      height: 10,
      width: 10,
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

I tried the code above but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Suffix` instead of `SuffixIcon`

Comment: Hi my `TextFormField` is taller. How to solve?

Comment: sorry i don't understood,can you share your  textFormField code?

Comment: I have a space above my hint text

Comment: What is the problem with it and how do you want it to look like?

Comment: Here's the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UFFA.png

Comment: I'm not getting the problem, are you using  `padding` or `contentPadding`?

Comment: Oh sorry, this is my own code problem. Sorry for taking your time

Comment: @MyCar how did you solve your the problem (i.stack.imgur.com/6UFFA.png) ?

Answer (score 2):

wrap `suffixIcon` widget in an `UnconstrainedBox`. It worked like a charm.

Original Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64009622/12267888

Answer (score 0):

```
const UnconstrainedBox(
    child: SizedBox(
      height: 20,
      width: 20,
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 0.7),
    ),
  )
```

This is the solution to the problem.
Original answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77578229/21971061